# Set MongoDB write concern through mgo driver

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have a Go client that repeatedly inserts data into **MongoDB** for 1 minute. I don't want the writes to be acknowledged to the client until they are replicated to the secondary of my primary-secondary-arbiter replica set, so I specified **majority** write concern through the **mongo** shell.

However, the client's execution completes far ahead of the writes being replicated to the secondary (I'm watching the doc count to be sure). If the primary were to crash before the replication is done, data would be rolled back that--from the client's perspective--had already been acknowledged.

Doesn't this behavior contradict the majority write concern I set through the shell? Do I also need to set the write concern through the mgo driver? This article suggests I need to:

**[Running MongoDB Queries Concurrently With Go](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/80579086742/running-mongodb-queries-concurrently-with-go)**

> We use the `mgo.DialWithInfo` method to create a `mgo.Session` object. Each session specifies a Strong or Monotonic mode, and other settings such as write concern and read preference.

But I don't see anything in the `mgo` driver docs about setting write concern. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for ([full documentation](http://gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Session.SetSafe)):

```
session.SetSafe(&mgo.Safe{WMode: "majority"})
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. I think it's confusing that mgo uses the terms "safety mode" and "consistency mode" to refer to write concern and read preference, respectively.

Comment: It's the price of having these available years before these terms even existed.